# "Delete query" not able to be completed

Tags: mysql, query

I have a very simple mysql script that is running. But it hangs, and runs forever without finishing. What are possible reasons, and how can I resolve them?

`delete from guid_target_infos where type_id = 1 and updated_at < '2010-03-14' limit 1`

UPDATE: 
show processlist

```
|  93 | mysql | localhost             | TwAnalyzer_dev | Query   |  257 | updating | delete  from guid_target_infos where type_id = 1 and updated_at < '2010-03-14' limit 1 |
```

(Everything else - Command is SLEEP, and info is NULL)

Comment: the script only has this query? If it has other queries, are you sure that the script hangs in this specific one?

Comment: Yup! Innotop says this query is running  has been running forever. I suspect something is locking up the particular table

Comment: and when you do a "show processlist" when the delete is running, what does it show?

Comment: what's the engine? myisam? innodb? another?

Comment: just to be pedantic and be certain this isn't true; are you running this from a shell, and did you leave off the ';' on the end?

Comment: The output will be easier to read if you use SHOW PROCESSLIST\G instead of SHOW PROCESSLIST;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try `show table status <tablename>;` and see if that shows anything unusual.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html

Comment: also: http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/07/31/how-to-analyze-innodb-mysql-locks/ a guide on analyzing innodb table locks...

Comment: Thanks! I tried the steps he mentioned. but there seems to be the ONLY transaction - no other transaction is running! And i have even rebooted the server (not just restart the mysql), so i am very confused

Answer (score 0):

if your storage engine is innodb try increasing [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) in my.cnf

Comment: It is not increasing timeout. I suspect something is locking it up. How can I see what are the possible things that are locking it up?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the `limit 1`?

Comment: hmm, what for? i would not be able to track the progress