# How can i see what is locking up a table?

Tags: mysql, process, database-administration, locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Delete query” not able to be completed](https://serverfault.com/questions/142217/delete-query-not-able-to-be-completed)

I am trying to delete a single row from the db, but it is not completing,even in 20 minutes.There is no other queries locking up the db. I suspect it is some "leftover" lock from previous operations. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: the table is myisam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show processlist

And maybe enable slow query log

Comment: +1 for informing me of 'slow query log' feature in mysql, that's really nice...